# Android Emulator closes itself

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Month or couple ago my emulator started to get close (maybe crash?) every time I press `ctrl` button on keyboard or when I click emulator's rightside buttons (take screenshot, rotate screen etc..).

It's very annoying, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution.1**

By setting the **Graphics option** on the Android Virtual Device to **Software** instead of **Automatic** or **Hardware**. Once you did that the emulator device started up great and everything worked.

Or

Go to **Menu->Tools->Android** and uncheck the option Enable ADB Integration Run the application. Now the emulator will be launched, but the app will not run. Once the emulator is fully launched, check the Enable ADB Integration option and re-run the app. Now the app will be launched in the already running emulator.

**Solution.2**

You might have forwarding enabled on adb. You can try this: Quit Android studio and launch terminal. Run these commands:

- adb kill-server
- adb forward --remove-all
- adb start-server

Now you can launch the Android Studio and try again.

I hope one of the solution work for you.
Thank You!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, Solution 1 didn't help me. I have only one option in advanced settings of my emulator: Automatic. Also: could you explain more detailed, what is "Menu->Tools->Android"? I have no "android" option in "Tools"-section.

Solution 2 didn't help me too.

Answer (score 3):

i made oneother divice with lower sdk version and worked for me, latest version was 11, so i made the new device in emulator with sdk v10

Comment: This worked for me. MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

**I'll leave this here it may help someone in the future.**

I was using the emulator normally when it suddenly stopped working. I tried to find what was the last thing I had changed in the IDE, and it was changing the Boot Java runtime from **Help -> Find action**. Then I searched for **"choose boot Java runtime for IDE"**

[image]

and press **"use default Java runtime."**

[image]

After restarting the IDE, you are good to go. This is only one of the solutions out there that may or may not work for you. In my case, it did work.

Why did I change the Java version from first place? It was because .md files weren't rendering, and a solution suggested using a Java version with JCEF.